# surround each of the array items with the `^` sign

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I want to surround each of the following array items with the `^` sign like this:

```
const signs = [',', '!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '؟!', '!؟', '!', '؟', ':'];

const input = 'this is, a text?'

// this is the desired result : 'this is ^,^ a text ^?^'
```

as you see if there is no space between the item and the word next to it a space should be added too.

I used a complex function to do this but I think this could be done easily with regex too.

How would you do this ?

here is the function (which still is in development ):

```
function modifySelectedPortion(e) {

        
        const translateSigns = translationInput.value.split(' ').filter(s => acceptedSigns.includes(s));
        if(translateSigns.length) {
            console.log(translateSigns);
        }

        const selectionEnd = translationInput.selectionEnd;
        const selectionStart = translationInput.selectionStart;


        const color = e.target.dataset.color;
        if(!color) return;
        const signs = { blue: '|', red: '$', orange: '^', purple: '#', green: '~', quote: '@', braket: 'braket', pranthesis: 'pranthesis' };
        if(color == 'none') return reset();
        if(color == 'copy') return copy();
        const signA = color == 'bracket' ? '[ ' : color == 'pranthesis' ? '( ' : signs[color];
        const signB = color == 'bracket' ? ' ]' : color == 'pranthesis' ? ' )' : signs[color];
        const point = translationInput.value[selectionEnd - 1];
        const increase = ['bracket', 'pranthesis'].includes(color) ? 2 : 1;
        // const start = translationInput.selectionStart;
        const finish = point == ' ' ? selectionEnd + increase - 1: selectionEnd + increase;
        const textStart = translationInput.value;
        translationInput.value = textStart.substring(0, selectionStart) + signA + textStart.substring(selectionStart);
        const textFinish = translationInput.value;
        translationInput.value = textFinish.substring(0, finish) + signB + textFinish.substring(finish);

        translationInputPreview();
        function reset() {
            for(let key of Object.keys(signs)) {
                translationInput.value = translationInput.value.replaceAll(signs[key], '');
            }
            translationInputPreview();
        }
        function copy() {
            translationInput.value = getCookie('translate-input') || '';
            translationInputPreview();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with regex

```js
const signs = [',', '!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '؟!', '!؟', '!', '؟', ':'];

const input = 'this is, a text?'

const str = signs.map(e => e.replace(/\?/g, '\\?').replace(/\./g, '\\.')).join('|')

const regex = new RegExp(` ?(${str}) ?`, 'g')

const result = input.replace(regex, ' ^$1^ ').trim()

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Well done, just one more question, what if we want not to add extra `^` when re run the function on the string ?

Comment: @SaraRee please give an example input and output

Comment: `this is ^,^ a text ^?^ !` as input should result in `this is ^,^ a text ^?^ ^!^`

Answer (score 0):

I think we could use Regex in this issue

```js
const input = 'this is, a text? are you happy !! haha';
const regex = /(!!|,|\?\?)/g
console.log(input.replaceAll(regex, "^$1^"))
// output: this is^,^ a text? are you happy ^!!^ haha
```

I created a group `(!!|,|\?\?)`, it means find characters that matches `!!`, `,` or `??`. And the `|` means OR

So, you can put your `[',', '!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '؟!', '!؟', '!', '؟', ':']` inside the brackets and split them with `|` to resolve the issue

Hope it helpful !

Comment: well done ......

Comment: what if we want not to add extra ^ when re run the function on the string. for instance this is ^,^ a text ^?^ ? as input should result in this is ^,^ a text ^?^ ^?^

Answer (score 0):

Create a regex that matches any of the elements in your `signs` array.

`const pattern = /,|\?/`

I only added ',' and '?' to the pattern, you can add the rest, just be careful to escape the special characters properly like I did with the `?`.

Then you can do

```js
"this is, a text?".replace(pattern, x => '^' + x + '^')
```

Which will output `'this is^,^ a text^?^'`

Comment: well done ......

Comment: what if we want not to add extra ^ when re run the function on the string. for instance this is ^,^ a text ^?^ ? as input should result in this is ^,^ a text ^?^ ^?^

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by iterating the `signs` array and then do [`String.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const signs = [',', '!!', '?!', '!?', '...', '..', '.', '?', '؟!', '!؟', '!', '؟', ':'];

let input = 'this is, a text?';

signs.forEach(c => input = input.replaceAll(c, ` ^${c}^`));

console.log(input);
```